# How ACPI Tables are sent to linux from SeaBIOS

Tags: c, linux, x86, linux-device-driver, acpi

I am working on linux device drivers on intel atom rangeley board. We can use DTS and ACPI for providing platform device information.

I am currently using ACPI Tables, want to understand how ACPI tables are transferred to linux through SeaBIOS.

Correct me if i am thinking wrong, Thanks in advance .

Comment: It's all written in the ACPI specifications. The TL;DR: there is an entry point to the ACPI tables with magic number at the 16-byte alined address in BIOS memory address range. When you find that in OS, you may traverse through the entire ACPI data and recreate ACPI namespace (that's what ACPICA is doing in the Linux kernel).